# how to suppress warning messages from `ggplot2`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am deliberately choosing to display an axis and its labels in a certain way in `ggplo2` and that produces some `warning` messages, which I would prefer not to be printed to the user's console.

How can I silence them?

```r
library(ggplot2)

suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
      sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis(
        name = NULL,
        labels = parse(text = "widehat(mu)[median]=='3.2'"),
        breaks = 3.2
      )
    )
))
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By explicitly calling `print` we can make sure that `supressWarnings` suppresses the right thing ;)

```
library(ggplot2)

suppressWarnings(print(
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
      sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis(
        name = NULL,
        labels = parse(text = "widehat(mu)[median]=='3.2'"),
        breaks = 3.2
      )
    )
))
```

P.S. While I understand what you want to achieve, wouldn't a `geom_vline` be less "experimental" ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me because this function is just a small part of a large function. Using `print` here would mean, I will be plotting twice: once here and another time at the end of the function.

Comment: ;) its enough when you wrap the final print call. But even better would be to use another solution, where you don't get warnings.