# Trying to suppress ggplot2 warning about introducing infinite values in log-transformed axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to suppress a ggplot2 warning about infinite values being introduced with no luck. Here are some dummy data:

```
DF <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = -1:8)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
   geom_point() + scale_y_log10()
```

Since I've log transformed the y axis, that's a problem for -1 (NaN) and for 0 (-Inf). I know ggplot2 is trying to be helpful when it warns

> Warning messages:
> 1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
> 2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis
> 3: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).

but these graphs are part of a function with multiple graphs, and I don't want multiples of the same warning, especially since other people will use this function and may be confused by it.

**How can I suppress this warning?**

This does not work:

```
suppressWarnings(ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
   geom_point() + scale_y_log10())
```

Nor does this:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
geom_point() + scale_y_log10(oob = scales::oob_censor_any)
```

And this other question doesn't actually give a good answer for when ggplot is called within a function: [how to suppress warning messages from `ggplot2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167903/how-to-suppress-warning-messages-from-ggplot2)

Comment: Would you be open to modifying your data before the `ggplot` to avoid warnings? You could just run `DF %>% filter(Y > 0) %>% ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10()` -- it won't make any lasting changes to your data and will give you no warnings

Comment: I suppose that *is* a possible workaround. Hmm... Good, straightforward way to address this!

Comment: Ah, yes, I remembered when I went to implement this that I had added a spot in my function where I've *intentionally* set an x value to -Inf because I'm plotting with geom_rect and I want the left edge of the rectangle to be right at the y axis. This won't solve that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider my favorite scale transformation, which is mostly log but smoothly converts to a linear scale for the range near zero (within +/- `sigma`). This allows it to gracefully accept and display zeros and negative numbers, while still keeping a log appearance for larger values.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  # scale_y_log10()
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.01),
                     breaks = c(-1, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 1, 10), minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, interesting! I hadn't been aware of scales::pseudo_log_trans! I'll see if that will work.

Comment: Actually, hold up: This changes the visual distance between the intervals at the lower end of the scale. That won't work. I need the distance between, e.g., 0.1 and 1 to be the same as the distance between 1 and 10. That's the whole reason for log transforming that axis in the first place. Sorry! I didn't notice this at first!

Comment: Updated with adjustment to make the space from 0.1 to 1 match the space from 1 to 10. The tricky part here is how you want to treat 0 to 0.1. With sigma at 0.01, the space from 0 to 0.1 is about (exactly?) the same as the 10x changes beyond that range.